# Unable to get value of SfMaskedEdit and SfNumericTextBox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am unable to get value of dynamically added SfMaskedEdit and SfNumericTextBox.

```
SfNumericTextBox num = new SfNumericTextBox();
num.StyleId = q.Id + "-x";
num.MaximumNumberDecimalDigits = 0;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.Suffix))
    num.FormatString = q.Suffix;
//num.MaximumNumberDecimalDigits = 99999;
num.Watermark = "Enter numbers";

num.Unfocused += Num_Unfocused;
num.TextColor = Color.FromHex("303030");
testContainer.Children.Add(num);


    private void Num_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        SfNumericTextBox obj = (SfNumericTextBox)sender;
        keyValues.AddOrUpdate(id, Convert.ToString(obj.Value), (key, oldValue) => Convert.ToString(obj.Value));//obj.Value is always null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the Value property of the SfNumericTextBox in the Unfocused event, where the entered value is properly available in all the platforms (Android, iOS and UWP). We are afraid that, we are not able to reproduce the issue at our end. We have attached the tested sample, please download it from the following location.

Sample:https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/NumericTxtBox1870210506

Also, we would like to suggest you that, you can use the ValueChanged event to get the value of the SfNumericTextBox from the event arguments (ValueEventArgs(e.Value)). Please check the attached sample and let us know if you face any problem.

Refer the below documentation link to know more about ValueChanged event. 
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfnumerictextbox/events-and-interactivity#valuechanged

Regards, 
Rachel.